# Populate an array with objects from a fetch

Tags: php, arrays

Relatively new to PHP here, so I'm probably trying to do too much.

I have an object, Group, and I'm getting all the groups from a database and pushing them to an array before sending it to my view.

So I have:

```
$groups=array();
$group=new Group();
$stmt=$databaseconnection->prepare("SELECT Id, Name, Description FROM Groups");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($group->Id, $group->Name, $group->Description);

while($stmt->fetch()){
   $groups[]=$group;
   $group=new Group();
   }

return $groups;
```

this returns an array of elements numbering the total of elements I should have in the array but they are all the same as the last element.  if I have 3 groups and the last one is "Users" I have an array with 3 elements that are all "Users".

Why does this happen?  What's the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind_result stores the columns into the variables on each fetch call, so you would need to create a new group each time and set the group's data members to the appropriate values.

```
...
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $description);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    $group = new Group();
    $group->Id = $id;
    $group->Name = $name;
    $group->Description = $description;

    $groups[] = $group;
}
return $groups;
```

Comment: Gah, this makes some of my longer queries and bigger objects a real pain.  Glad I didn't get too far ahead of myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One fun trick I have to simplify when doing things like this different way:

in my repository classes I have a function that returns a single item based on the Id, then I have another class that returns various groups of the items. So I handle that like this:

```
$collection = array();

$stmt=$connect->prepare("SELECT Id FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE CRITERIA=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $Whatever);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    $collection[] = $this->getItem($id);
    }
```

(getItem returns a build out object based on the id passed)

This is useful when you need to have a single selector and a multiple selector, and very useful when you have lots of attributes/properties in your class (you only have to type out the prepared statement, bound parameters, bound results, and attribute assignments once).

Alternatively, you could populate the array, then close the database connection, then do a foreach on the array to save the connections.